# Slide image with carousel from storage could not start without active class

Tags: laravel-5

I want to load an image from my storage folder Laravel 5.6 and put it into image slider Carousel Bootstrap 4 but when I did with `foreach` loop laravel it stacked. is there any way to do like I want to? I am sorry my English not so good, Thanks!

Here is my blade view

```html
@extends('layout.home') @section('content')

<div class="mt-4">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner m-auto">

      @if(count($products)>0) @foreach($products as $product)
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-75" src="/storage/product_images/{{$product->product_image}}" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      @endforeach @else
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-75" src="/storage/product_images/noimage.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      @endif
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>Profile</h1>
  <p class="text-justify"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>

</div>

@endsection
```

Here is the failed slide

[failed slide with stacked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqBcK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it by changing

```html
<div class="carousel-item">
    ...
</div>
```

into :

```html
<div class="carousel-item @if($product->id === $product->first()->id) {{ 'active' }} @endif">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this

```
 <img class="d-block w-75" src="/storage/product_images/{{$product->product_image}}" alt="First slide">
```

use like this

```
  <img class="d-block w-75" src="{{ asset('storage/product_images/'.$product->product_image) }}" alt="First slide">
```

asset() function indicates to root of your folder